# fetch only some part of a MP4 over HTTP

Tags: http, mp4, chunks

I want to retrieve only the last x seconds of a MP4 file located on a remote http server thanks to 'Range' HTTP Header.
How can I know which bytes I need to retrieve? Is there the file structure somewhere?